# Properties on anonymous types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript2.0

I am trying to check a property on an anonymous type in a Lambda expression in TypeScript.

[image]

This won't compile:

> Build: Property 'infomodel' does not exist on type '{}'.

The `sn.app.map.Markers` array is of type `any`